# find index of a specific number row wise

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example

```
A =

     6     9     4     7    10
     3     6     5     5     9
    10     4     9     8     6
    10     6     3     4     6
     6     3     3     8     6
     6     4     4     4     5
     5    10     8     5     7
    10    10     8     8     7
     5     7     8     9     9
     3     3     6     3     9

[~,Inx] =max(A, [],2)

Inx =

     5
     5
     1
     1
     4
     1
     2
     1
     4
     5
```

The above code returns index of the maximum number along each column like in first row the max number is 10 in 5th row so `Inx(1) = 5` 
Can we do the same thing for find ? like for example if I want to find a specific number in each row lets say 8

```
>> find(A == 8)

ans =

    27
    28
    29
    33
    35
    38
```

I will get the indices but not row wise like we get for the `max()` is there some way to do minipulate find to get that ? or else some other way

Update : I know we can use `[row,col,v] = find(___)` but there is one problem with that it only returns for the rows where the value is present

Comment: What do you want it to return where the value is not present? I'm a bit confused what exactly you're after...

Comment: like it should return 0 maybe or a nan in its place

Comment: Aha, so for each _row_, you want to check if there is a number, and if there isn't it should return 0? I recommend thinking a bit if you really want this, if you try to use these indices you will get errors...

Comment: Yes exactly , like if it is present the column number else a 0

Comment: reshape to a vector and use sub2ind, then you can check for missing entries

Comment: @Umar What if it is present in multiple columns...

Comment: Just considers the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert `A` to a logical matrix where it's `1` if equal to `8` and `0` otherwise. Then you can use the second output of `max` to find the column which contains the first `8` in each row. If a row doesn't contain any `8`'s the first output of `max` will be a `0` and the second output will be `1`. 
You can multiply the first and second outputs to zero-out these rows that didn't have an `8`.

```
[has8, col] = max(A == 8, [], 2);

% Zero out any rows that didn't contain an 8
result = has8 .* col;

%   0
%   0
%   4
%   0
%   4
%   0
%   3
%   3
%   3
%   0
```

If you'd rather have `NaN`'s than `0`'s, you could do the following which exploits the fact that `0/0 == NaN`

```
result = has8 .* col ./ has8;

%   NaN
%   NaN
%     4
%   NaN
%     4
%   NaN
%     3
%     3
%     3
%   NaN
```

Comment: Perfect thats what i was looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for the update , it made it much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
Inx = zeros(size(A,1),1); % initialize with default values
[row,col,v] = find(A==8); % find the proper indices
Inx(row) = col; % insert values
```

Comment: Its the same as using [row,col,v] = find(___) :)